# Format a telephone number in an INPUT on the fly

Tags: jquery, phone-number

I'm looking for a function that will reformat a telephone number as the person is typing it in so it will come out as: (212) 477-1000

I found a snippet and created a function that will take the value and reformat it. Does anyone know of another snippet that will format 2124771000 as the person types it in "on the fly"?

---

```
<input value="2124771000" type=text id="DPRnumber">


$('#DPRnumber').on('click', 'input', function(e){

    $(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
        text = text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
        return text;
    });
}
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DAgqU/?

Comment: Keyup was what I was wondering about.
That evaluates the complete number when entered. 
But what about laying out (212) first and then laying out 477 then add hypen then this could revaluate everything when all 10 digits are entered.

Comment: Is that a problem? What did you want it to do, format the number as it's being typed instead of when it's been completely entered?

Comment: Yes, format the number as it's being typed

Answer (score 0):

I know its long but It works really well.

```
<script language="javascript">
var zChar = new Array(' ', '(', ')', '-', '.');
var maxphonelength = 14;
var phonevalue1;
var phonevalue2;
var cursorposition;

function ParseForNumber1(object){
  phonevalue1 = ParseChar(object.value, zChar);
}

function ParseForNumber2(object){
phonevalue2 = ParseChar(object.value, zChar);
}

function backspacerUP(object,e) { 
  if(e){ 
    e = e 
  } else {
 e = window.event 
  } 
  if(e.which){ 
    var keycode = e.which 
  } else {
    var keycode = e.keyCode 
  }

  ParseForNumber1(object)

  if(keycode >= 48){
    ValidatePhone(object)
  }
}

function backspacerDOWN(object,e) { 
 if(e){ 
 e = e 
 } else {
  e = window.event 
 } 
 if(e.which){ 
  var keycode = e.which 
 } else {
   var keycode = e.keyCode 
  }
  ParseForNumber2(object)
} 

function GetCursorPosition(){

 var t1 = phonevalue1;
    var t2 = phonevalue2;
 var bool = false
  for (i=0; i<t1.length; i++)
  {
   if (t1.substring(i,1) != t2.substring(i,1)) {
  if(!bool) {
     cursorposition=i
    window.status=cursorposition
      bool=true
     }
   }
  }
}

function ValidatePhone(object){

  var p = phonevalue1

  p = p.replace(/[^\d]*/gi,"")

  if (p.length < 3) {
    object.value=p
  } else if(p.length==3){
pp=p;
d4=p.indexOf('(')
d5=p.indexOf(')')
if(d4==-1){
  pp="("+pp;
}
if(d5==-1){
  pp=pp+")";
}
object.value = pp;
  } else if(p.length>3 && p.length < 7){
p ="(" + p; 
l30=p.length;
p30=p.substring(0,4);
p30=p30+") " 

p31=p.substring(4,l30);
pp=p30+p31;

object.value = pp; 

 } else if(p.length >= 7){
p ="(" + p; 
l30=p.length;
p30=p.substring(0,4);
p30=p30+") " 

p31=p.substring(4,l30);
pp=p30+p31;

l40 = pp.length;
p40 = pp.substring(0,9);
p40 = p40 + "-"

p41 = pp.substring(9,l40);
ppp = p40 + p41;

object.value = ppp.substring(0, maxphonelength);
  }

  GetCursorPosition()

  if(cursorposition >= 0){
if (cursorposition == 0) {
  cursorposition = 2
} else if (cursorposition <= 2) {
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 1
} else if (cursorposition <= 4) {
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 3
} else if (cursorposition == 5) {
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 3
} else if (cursorposition == 6) { 
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 3 
} else if (cursorposition == 7) { 
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 4 
} else if (cursorposition == 8) { 
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 4
  e1=object.value.indexOf(')')
  e2=object.value.indexOf('-')
  if (e1>-1 && e2>-1){
    if (e2-e1 == 4) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition - 1
    }
  }
} else if (cursorposition == 9) {
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 4
} else if (cursorposition < 11) {
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 3
} else if (cursorposition == 11) {
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 1
} else if (cursorposition == 12) {
  cursorposition = cursorposition + 1
} else if (cursorposition >= 13) {
  cursorposition = cursorposition
}

var txtRange = object.createTextRange();
txtRange.moveStart( "character", cursorposition);
txtRange.moveEnd( "character", cursorposition - object.value.length);
txtRange.select();
 }

}

function ParseChar(sStr, sChar)
{

  if (sChar.length == null) 
   {
    zChar = new Array(sChar);
  }
    else zChar = sChar;

  for (i=0; i<zChar.length; i++)
  {
  sNewStr = "";

  var iStart = 0;
  var iEnd = sStr.indexOf(sChar[i]);

  while (iEnd != -1)
  {
    sNewStr += sStr.substring(iStart, iEnd);
    iStart = iEnd + 1;
    iEnd = sStr.indexOf(sChar[i], iStart);
    }
    sNewStr += sStr.substring(sStr.lastIndexOf(sChar[i]) + 1, sStr.length);

    sStr = sNewStr;
  }

  return sNewStr;
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do I call the function?

From any INPUT?

Comment: In stead of using<br><input value="" type=text id="DPRnumber" onkeydown="javascript:backspacerDOWN(this,event);" onkeyup="javascript:backspacerUP(this,event);"><br>
Is there an easier way to call these functions using jquery<br>
$('#DPRnumber')... something?

Comment: I would the script you have. <input value="" type=text id="DPRnumber" onkeydown="javascript:backspacerDOWN(this,event);" onkeyup="javascript:backspacerUP(this,event);">. This seems like the easiest way I know.